# Illegal tokens added after modifying the file inside data volume

Tags: php, apache, docker, boot2docker

I have installed Docker Toolbox, and created container with Apache and PHP like this:

```
docker run -d --name name -p 80:80  \
   -v //c/Users/name/public_html:/var/www \
    name/image
```

However, now, every time I modify the files inside public_html, Web server says that illegal tokens are added:

[image]

This is weird, I never had this kind of problem before with old boot2docker, or maybe it's something wrong with the image ?

Comment: I have just found that this happens only with this specific image that I've built...can anyone suggest where to look, how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Apache config was missing this:

```
EnableMMAP off
EnableSendfile off
```